# Drupal User Permissions, Only Allow Specific Users to Edit Specific Pages

Tags: drupal

I know I can set up a role to allow user's to only edit their own pages, then go mark the appropriate pages to be authored by the appropriate user. But then I run into multiple users per page problems.

Is there any way that you can explicitly only allow a user to edit certain (perhaps multiple) pages, while accounting for overlap in the case that more than one user may be allowed to edit the same page?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a module that set the access permissions of a user to a node of a specific content type, then use http://drupal.org/project/content_access; if the content type is a book, then you can also try http://drupal.org/project/book_access.
Remember that installing different modules for access control should be avoided, as they tend to conflict each with the other.

If you have patience, then you can create your own custom module, and implement `hook_node_access_records()` and `hook_node_grants()` as suggested by Jeremy.

Answer (score 2):

This would be fairly complex to do programmatically, but a fairly easy solution is to create a vocabulary to apply to the pages and then use the taxonomy access control module: http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access to set the permissions based on terms.

Comment: I suggest tac_lite, it's a bit less heavy, and it offers the flexibility to configure individuals users instead of just roles.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question a few months ago, with an overview of implementing a few different access scenarios:
[How do I give a specific user editing rights to a specific node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289004/drupal-how-do-i-give-a-specific-user-editing-rights-to-a-specific-node/2291909#2291909)

Answer (score 1):

try http://drupal.org/project/coherent_access

or http://drupal.org/project/content_access

this ish is crazy!@!!!@!@!

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible to do programatically using [hook_nod_access_records()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_node_access_records/6) and [hook_node_grants()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_node_access_records/6).

With hook node_access_record create a relm with the UIDs of the users you wish to allow. and in hook grants create a grant with the users uid in the same relm. It is not that scary and very flexable.